# Acegi User Class constraints under groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, validation, spring-security

I have an Groovy appilcation using Acegi Spring Security.

My User Class looks as follows:

```
class User {
static constraint  = {
  email(blank:true, nullable:true) 
  description(blank:false, nullable:false) 
  username(blank: false, unique: true)
      userRealName(blank: false)
      company(nullable:true, blank:true)
      authorities()
      enabled()
      passwd(blank: false)
}

static mapping = {
    table 'user_table'
}

static transients = ['pass']
static hasMany = [authorities: Role]
static belongsTo = Role
String username
String userRealName
String passwd
boolean enabled
String email
boolean emailShow
String description = ''
String pass = '[secret]'

Company company
```

}

Note that company **is** nullable and username **is not** nullable.
I've generated the the views and the controller without any problem.
When I try to insert a new user (without company) I am getting an error
message telling my that the company **IS** compulsory. (I've verified 
the field at the DB and it is nullable)

On the other hand when I generate a user without username -which should be forbidden-
the validator doens't report any error although an exception is coming 
when trying to insert a null into a non-nullable field.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Luis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "static constraint" to "static constraints".